# Can I Romance Ashley even though I did not in ME1, and I did Romance Miranda in ME2?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Can I Romance Ashley even though I did not in ME1, and I did Romance Miranda in ME2?
Or am I stuck with Miranda?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You can abandon your previous relationship with Miranda to pursue Ashley in Mass Effect 3.

As a rule of thumb, you can initiate a romance with characters returning from *Mass Effect*, who were romance options in that title, and new characters introduced in *Mass Effect 3*. You **cannot** initiate a romance with characters introduced in *Mass Effect 2*, or characters who were introduced *as romance options* in *Mass Effect 2*, but you can choose to **continue** those relationships if you began them in the prior title.